# TYPO3: Condition "if column empty"?

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, typoscript

I'm looking for a condition to check wether a certain column is empty.

Something like this:

```
[colPos.0 = empty]
#do stuff
[global]
```

Thanks in advance.

*Edit:*
I think it's quite unclear what I'm looking for. So let me add some information:

I've got a column for a teaser image in the BE (colPos = 0). If it contains an element, it should regularly display this element. If not (== if empty), it should use another image instead.

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 do you use and which template engine? I.e. if you use Fluid - you could just use `f:if` condition, otherwise check this snippet: https://typo3.org/documentation/snippets/sd/110/

Comment: @biesior well I couldn't figure out how to use your snippet, but it gave me another idea which lead to the solution. Just added `<f:if condition="{col0}">` into my fluid template. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is of course a possibility to show stuff wether a Column has content or not,
but there is no TS-condition for this.

based on https://kuttler.eu/en/post/change-template-if-content-exists-in-typo3/,
here is my solution for this:

```
temp.foo {
temp.foo = COA

    10 = COA
    10 {
        10 < styles.content.get
        10.select.where = colPos=1

        # conditional to test if content exists in column
        if.isTrue.numRows {
            # check current page page
            pidInList = this
            # in the table tt_content
            table = tt_content
            # colPos = 1
            select.where = colPos=1
        }
    }

    20 = COA
    20 {
        10 < lib.somethingElse

        # conditional to test if content exists in column
        if.isFalse.numRows {
            # check current page page
            pidInList = this
            # in the table tt_content
            table = tt_content
            # colPos = 1
            select.where = colPos=1
        }
    }
}
```

`if.isTrue` and `if.isFalse` are doing the trick here.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**`if`** function](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/If/Index.html), sample (from doc):

```
page.10 = COA_INT
page.10.10 = TEXT
page.10.10 {
  stdWrap.if.isNull.field = description
  value = No description available.
}
```

Edit: Also, if you are using Fluid template, you can just use `f:if` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I'm trying to check the content of the columns, if they are filled with content elements or not. Give me a minute, I'll edit the question for more clearance.